# Tween Engine or Scene2d Actions?

Tags: java, animation, libgdx, tween, scene2d

I'm currently getting used to using libGDX. I've been using Tween Engine for animations and such, but there is also an Actions class.

My question is simple: Which one is better: Tween, or Scene2D Actions? With that, I'd also like it if someone could offer an explanation on their differences and flexibility. Could it also be a good idea to use both at the same time for specific needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on situation - Scene2D Actions are available only when you are using Scene2D Stage/Actors. With Tween you are not limited to Scene2D so you can easily work with Sprites or your own implementations. Tween has more options.

Comment: Alright! I know what I'll be using. Thanks!